# Do multiple calls to Distinct() matter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Suppose I have a query where I'm expecting to have a lot of duplicate data, like this

```
var scienceDorms = dbContext.Classes
    .Where(c => c.Subject = "Science")
    .SelectMany(c => c.Students)
    .Distinct()
    .SelctMany(s => s.Dorms)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Does the presence of more than 1 `Distinct()` statement help here?

If this were linq to objects, I would assume that the first call to `Distinct()` would greatly reduce the amount of data that goes to the second `SelectMany()`.

however, my knowledge of the inner workings of Entity Framework and sql are somewhat sketchy, and I'm worried that that extra call to `Distinct` might just complicate the sql that's generated by EF without giving me much benefit, or even worse, somehow compromise some sort of optimization that EF or SQL might do behind the scenes.

Does the multiple calls to `Distinct` actually help?

Comment: Check the SQL query generated for both cases.

Comment: I bellieve it does make a difference when you overwrite Equals and GetHashcode, then there is a possibility that you will have different results. Though i dont know if this is taken into account in this particular case (EF)

Comment: The `c` in `.SelectMany(c => c.Student.Dorms)` is going to be a `Student`, so you probably just mean it to be `.Select(s => s.Dorm)`

Answer (score 0):

The multiple calls to `Distinct` will probably hurt your performance, actually. Because of the nature of LINQ to Entities all of those calls won't actually happen until the `.ToList()` call at the end since LINQ will employ deferred execution (see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx) about that), at which point the query builder will have to translate both that first `Distinct` and `SelectMany`, which has its own overhead (to say nothing of what extra bits that translated query may have--you'll need to check out the SQL Profiler for that, though).

I think you'd probably be better off doing something like this:

```
var scienceDorms = dbContext.Classes
                            .Where(c => c.Subject == "Science")
                            .SelctMany(c => c.Students.SelectMany(s => s.Dorms))
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

This will remove both of those clauses, which should reduce the overhead from query generation, and will give you the same results.